# Cordova/phonegap project not copying template files

Tags: cordova

I'm running into issues on windows 7 where on running:

```
D:\sdks\incubator-cordova-android\bin>create d:/projects/mycotest com.example.mycotest MyCoTest
```

and getting the following output

```
Microsoft (R) Windows Script Host Version 5.8
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Creating new android project...
Building jar and js files...
Copying template files...
Copying js, jar & config.xml files...
Copying cordova command tools...
Updating AndroidManifest.xml and Main Activity...
```

The created project can be compiled in eclipse/android sdk however it does not actually contain any cordova/phonegap files, but instead is just the default android hello world example.

I have tried both the incubator github version of cordova
https://github.com/apache/incubator-cordova-android

and the downloadable 2.4.0 from the website.

Edit:

On a windows Vista x86 machine here the project creates fine. On another windows 7 x64 machine the project fails in the same way. Seems to be a windows 7 problem. Anyone got a workaround?

Edit:

This problem is also confirmed on windows 8 with both cordova and phonegap. Sometimes with the error popup "Microsoft Console Based Script Host has stopped working"

Edit:

A temporary workaround is to create the project on a windows machine < 7. Then copy the project over and everything works fine after that. I'm going to leave this question unanswered for now as the original problem still stands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have faced the same issue, after looking inside the create script I found that the issue is with the project path.
You just simply need to change the forward slash `/` to back slash `\`.

```
d:\projects\mycotest
```

Comment: had the same issue. This saved so much of my time. Thx alot :)